# I am trying to iterate a xlsx files in specified path.How to exclude specified file

Tags: python, delete-file

i have 3 xlsx sheet in particular directory.I am combining into workbook.While combining,i need to exclude specified file.

```
Path="C:/JackDaniels/100Pipers/"
name="Panic"
writer=ExcelWriter(Path+name+"*.xlsx")#creating a workbook in name "name")
inp=glob.glob(Path+"*.xlsx")
inp=inp.remove(Path+name+"*.xlsx")#to remove ths file to avoid overwrite

# I have a code that will combine sheets
```

when i tried to run the above code am getting below error

```
list.remove(x):x not in list
```

Comment: try to print out `Path+Exc_file+*.xlsx` and you will propably see why it can't find `x`

Comment: @Rabinzel-it priints "C:/JackDaniels/100Pipers/S_P.xlsx"

Comment: no it doesn't. I knew it and I just checked it myself. if you run the line `print(Path+Exc_file+*.xlsx)` the output is `C:/JackDaniels/100Pipers/S_P.xlsx*.xlsx`. The `"*.xlsx"` at the end is wrong.

Comment: @Rabinzel..Thanks for pointing out...I removed that.But again am getiing the same error

Comment: then you need to find out why it can't find it. `print(int)` and see if `C:/JackDaniels/100Pipers/S_P.xlsx` is in that list and if not you need to find out why. I mean the error is really clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is really not clear and you should rephrase it.
If you are trying to combine them in the sense that you want to append all the three sheets to a new empty sheet (for example all of your sheets have same columns) you should make a python file in the same directory as your excel worksheets:

```py
import copy
import os
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.getcwd()

# list to store files
xlsx_files = []
exc_file = 'Exclude.xlsx'  # <-- The file name you want to exclude goes here.
out_file = 'Output.xlsx'   # <-- The output file name goes here.
# Iterate directory
for file in os.listdir(cwd):
    # check only Excel files
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        xlsx_files.append(file)
        
print("All xlsx files:", xlsx_files)

df = pd.DataFrame()
aux_files_var = copy.deepcopy(xlsx_files)
for file in aux_files_var:
    print(file)
    if file == exc_file or file == out_file: continue  # <-- here you exclude the file and the output
    df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True)
    xlsx_files.remove(file)
print(f"""As you can see, only exc_file remains in xlsx_files.
Remaining xlsx files:{xlsx_files}""")

print(df)
df.to_excel(out_file)
```

Comment: I have edited the code....Am not sure , why am getting this error....

Comment: See if the current answer solves

Comment: If my assumption was correct,it wil prompt "File is not zip file". 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71863539/how-to-combine-multi-excel-workbook-into-single-workbook-with-multiple-worksheet/71872752#71872752 ....These is my previous question

Comment: It takes one moment to try and test the code. I tried and tested it. It works.

Comment: Yes it worked.......thanks

Comment: Then you should upvote and accept the answer